# Issue with deploying Android App from eclipse to Blackberry Playbook Simulator

Tags: android, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-playbook

I created a small Android App that runs on the Android simulator/tablet just fine.. I used the Blackberry online repackaging tool for Android and it doesnt find any issue with the App.. But when I try to deploy it on to a BB PB simulator from eclipse the process stops at 70% for ever in eclipse.. I see my app on the PB simulator but it doesnt run if I directly run it within the PB simulator.. Is there a solution to this issue? Or is there some other way I can run the app on on the PB simulator.. I want to see how it looks on the PB simulator before I submit it in the BB App World.

EDIT::

I tried uninstall and reinstall twice already.. Doesnt help.. Rather than running it by using the "Run As" option of eclipse, I now got the keys from BB, signed the code and created the bar file. I used the eclipse BB option to install this on the Simulator and that works very well.. But when I run the app on the Simulator it just shows "Initializing.. Please wait" for a while and returns to the home screen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the issue was with the PB simulator... I submitted the app to BlackBerry AppWorld and it was approved....

Answer (score 0):

As obnoxious as it sounds, I would reinstall vmware and the simulator. I had similar issues, and nothing would solve them except a reinstall. Sometimes vmware can be wacky with the playbook sim.

Comment: also, id check your device configuration, make sure theres no silly errors in there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that twice already.. Doesnt help.. I Rather than running it by using the "Run As" option of eclipse, I now got the keys from BB, signed the code and created the bar file. I used the eclipse BB option to install this on the Simulator and that works very well.. But when I run the app on the Simulator it just shows "Initializing.. Please wait" for a while and returns to the home screen...

Comment: Any specific items to look for in the device config?

Comment: ah k well sry i wish i could be of more assistance, but im using flash builder, so im not sure about eclipse. Also, r u sure you have the beta 2 simulator? because if you r trying to port from android, it prob requires the android app emulator which is only found in os2. I'm not sure if that's included in the latest sim.

Comment: If you're up for it, i have a playbook sitting in front of me right now. I could sideload ur bar and test it out, see if it works on the actual device, then you wouldnt have to worry about it. That's all i got right now.

Comment: I am using the PB Simulator 2.. Downloaded it from the BB site yesterday.. Thanks for your offer to try out my app.. I have posted the question in the Blackberry support forums also.. Will look to see if they respond with an answer..

Comment: I would try to download a flash copy of eclipse and install the blackberry tools again

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.. What is a flash copy of eclipse... I am using the latest indigo version.. Sorry for the noob questions... I have started using eclipse only recently...